# GAE - updating structured properties ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to update an object and its properties within an ndb StructuredProperty object instead of appending?

Comment: Yes, there is. Can you show some code that you are having problems with?

Comment: Can you update the answer so people with the same problem can see your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for looking out but figured it out.  Appending the object to a list did the trick but I am sure there is a better efficient way.